Real numbers cos sin stuck on division
Problem:
Given $z_1 = e^{i\pi t/2}$ and $z_2 = e^{i\pi t/3}$, what is $\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)$.
My intuition tells me, that this is, $\cos(2\pi t/6)$.
But, I am stuck:
$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}t) \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t)$
$\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}t) \sin(\frac{\pi}{3}t)$
Note: I was told that, the correct solution must be: $\cos(\pi t/6)$

Just calculate it:
$z_1 = e^{i \pi t /2}$ and $z_2 = e^{i \pi t /3}$
Then:
$$\frac{z_1}{z_2} = e^{i \pi t \cdot (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3})}$$
You can easily calculate that $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$
Hence:
$$\frac{z_1}{z_2} = e^{i \pi t \cdot \frac{1}{6}}$$
Knowing that $e^{ix}=\cos(x) + i \sin(x)$, where $\Re(e^{ix}) = \cos(x)$ and $\Im(e^{ix}) = i \sin(x)$, you can derive:
$$\Re(\frac{z_1}{z_2}) = \cos(\pi t \cdot \frac{1}{6})$$
